# AWS API Gateway - Private Endpoint - message forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am trying to setup a private AWS API Gateway and connect to it from my laptop. The laptop resides in a network which is AWS Direct Connect'ed to a private VPC. I am using the toy-example "PetStore" API provided by AWS for this purpose.

According to [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html):

- established a API Gateway service endpoint to my VPC (private DNS disabled)
- gave it a security group that allows ALL inbound traffic from the
  local network (in which my laptop resides)
- created the API Gateway as private API
- updated the resource policy
- deployed the API as stage V1

Assume:

- **AWS account number**: 123456789012
- **AWS region**: eu-central-1
- **API Gateway ID**: abcdefghij
- **API Stage**: V1
- **VPC Endpoint Domanin**: vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
- **VPC Endpoint IP**: 10.10.10.10

To invoke my API, I call the following cURL command:

```
curl -v https://vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/V1/pets -H 'Host: abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' --noproxy "*"
```

and this is the result:

```
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com (10.54.251.244) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 240 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 240 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 4000
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4000 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5024 length 5024
* schannel: encrypted data length: 95
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 95 length 5024
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 252
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 347 length 5024
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 51
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 51 length 5024
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /V1/pets HTTP/1.1
> Host: vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 364
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 364 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 283
* schannel: decrypted data added: 283
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 283 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 52
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 52 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 23
* schannel: decrypted data added: 23
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 306 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 306 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 306
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: Server
< Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 11:32:01 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: a5aa9f76-4e3b-4315-838a-e859fa192ade
< x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: jdsak!291kd
<
{"message":"Forbidden"}* Connection #0 to host vpce-1234567890.execute-api.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com left intact
* Rebuilt URL to: abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'/
* Could not resolve host: abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
```

There is this `{"message":"Forbidden"}` which I am not sure from where it comes. And also the error `Could not resolve host: abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`.

So my question is: where this issue comes from?

### APPENDIX

#### Resource policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which method are you trying to hit? Get? Post?Put?

Comment: I am trying to hit GET

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: no, we tried to change the resource policy and even take this away from the direct connect setup to pure AWS (EC2 in VPC -> Endpoint -> API) but it is still the same issue

Comment: Try to create new api getway and not use the Pets template. if you need instructions, i wrote documentation - hit me on linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it really was **resource policy** related. After some other tries, we returned back to the former policy and somehow it started working (maybe we forgot to deploy the API first time)

This is the policy that **worked** for us:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Principal": "*" gives public access, what should be the Principal for private access, say it should be specific to user session and based on service account ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue that was related to Resource policy. try to use the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:${API_GETWAY_ID}/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "${VPC_ENDPOINT_ID}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, make sure the VPC Endpoint IDs include your vpce:

[image]

Comment: The resource policy probably should have "allow" : "StringEquals" and not "StringNotEquals" as this fits the template for "deny"; but good point - I will try to make the resource policy more explicit

Comment: i test this policy inside the VPC and outside the VPC and it worked. if there's an issue with this template, i'll change it.

Comment: I changed the resource policy, redeployed the API but still the same error

Comment: are you sure you hit to api getway from inside the vpc?

Comment: Your url should look something like that : `https://${API_Gateway_ID}.execute-api.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${APIGETWAY_STAGE}` https://imgur.com/cWW3hzk

Comment: I am invoking a private endpoint, thus using the VPC Endpoint domain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201452/discussion-between-amit-baranes-and-mlc).

Comment: Thanks for the answers and guidance @amit, somehow it started working = I just posted the answer above :)

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

The previous AWS API gateway private API configuration document is a bit misleading, I had pushed the update for the documentation.

When you create a private API gateway, there are two key fields you should pay attention to:

1. VPC endpoint ID
2. VPC ID

For VPC End Point Configuration under **APIs->Your API->Settings**:

```
Endpoint Configuration:
   VPC End Point ID:
       *Your VPC End Point ID(This is the VPC End point ID with     
    com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-1.execute-api permission)
```

Under **APIs->Your API->Resource Policy**, configure resource policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "Change to your VPC ID"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:123456789012:abcdefghij/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. But unless you redeploy your API the updated policy doesn't take effect.